# Batch File Argument Only Gets Passed The First Character

Tags: python, batch-file

I am trying to pass an argument to a batch file

My file only contains the following code:

```
set branch=%1
echo %branch%
```

calling the file with an argument `Foo`

outputs

`F`

I can't seem to find where is the syntax I got wrong.

Would love some help

---

As per request from the comments:

The full, exact script:

```
ECHO "Starting unit tests in get_unittests_results.bat"
@rem SET sainity_test_dir="C:\code\EPMD\%1\Templates\Testing\Main"
@rem SET testing_dir="C:\code\EPMD\%1\Templates\Testing"
@rem SET report_outcome_dir="%CD%\report_outcome"
@rem SET sainity_file_name="sanity.py"
@rem SET dev_epd_python_path="C:\DEV_EPD_Prerequisite\Anaconda2\python.exe"
@rem cd %sainity_test_dir%
@rem %dev_epd_python_path% %sainity_file_name%


ECHO %1
set branch=%1
ECHO %branch%
ECHO "Starting unit tests in get_unittests_results.bat"
SET dev_epd_python_path="C:\DEV_EPD_Prerequisite\Anaconda2\python.exe"
SET sainity_test_file_path="..\..\EPMD\%1\Templates\Testing\Main\sanity.py"
ECHO %dev_epd_python_path% %sainity_test_file_path%
%dev_epd_python_path% %sainity_test_file_path%
```

is called by a python script:

```
def run_batch(path, params):
    p = Popen(path.format(*params), cwd='.')
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
    if stderr is not None:
        print stderr

def create_unity_build(args):
    branch_name = args.branch
    run_batch(build_unity_script_path, [branch_name])
```

`args.branch` contains a string, longer than 1 in length (tested).

The batch only receives the first letter of that string (changes when I change that 1st letter).

Comment: While I'd use `set "branch=%~1"` I can't replicate that behaviour nor have an idea what could cause it.

Comment: Are you sure that is the entire content and layout of your batch file? Can you show us exactly how you're passing the argument?

Comment: @Compo Added the exact code as you requested.

Comment: @Gulzar, there wasn't enough space in the comment section, so I posted something in the answers section, to better reflect how the [tag:batch-file] should look. Please be aware that your script is using `%CD%` and relative paths, but doesn't first ensure that the current directory is set, before doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Python code, if `path` is a *string* of the batch-file path and `params` is a *list* of arguments, then would possibly use:

```
p = Popen([path] + params)
```

which concatenates (*extends*) a *list* with another *list*.

As for

```
p = Popen(path.format(*params), cwd='.')
```

path would need to be a pattern to be formatted, which I do not know the value and how is created. Seems odd as the path would be a pattern like i.e. `test.cmd {}`. Could omit `cmd='.'` as current directory would be default.

Answer (score 0):

As there is insufficient space to post this in the comments, I would suggest that you first adjust your [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) to better use doublequotes:

```bat
Rem Echo "Starting unit tests in get_unittests_results.bat"
Rem Set "sainity_test_dir=C:\code\EPMD\%~1\Templates\Testing\Main"
Rem Set "testing_dir=C:\code\EPMD\%~1\Templates\Testing"
Rem Set "report_outcome_dir=%CD%\report_outcome"
Rem Set "sainity_file_name=sanity.py"
Rem Set "dev_epd_python_path=C:\DEV_EPD_Prerequisite\Anaconda2\python.exe"
Rem CD /D "%sainity_test_dir%"
Rem "%dev_epd_python_path%" "%sainity_file_name%"

Echo %1
Set "branch=%~1"
Echo %branch%
Echo "Starting unit tests in get_unittests_results.bat"
Set "dev_epd_python_path=C:\DEV_EPD_Prerequisite\Anaconda2\python.exe"
Set "sainity_test_file_path=..\..\EPMD\%~1\Templates\Testing\Main\sanity.py"
Echo "%dev_epd_python_path%" "%sainity_test_file_path%"
"%dev_epd_python_path%" "%sainity_test_file_path%"
```

Comment: I don't understand the rules of when to use and when not to use quotes. Could you shortly explain?

Comment: @Gulzar, my advice is to always use them in the first instance, if an error results from it, start to remove them one pair at a time until you can determine which, if any, is causing an issue. As you can see the only places I haven't used them is in the `Echo` commands that you had already determined you didn't want them in.